# how to handle multiple textInput states created dynamically in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

How we can access values from  dynamically created Text Input. Like flat list creates 3 text inputs and then on click of button we validate which one is added and which one not. How to manage multiple state array. currently I done this

```
const data = [1,2];

constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  Textdata:[],
};

}

  SubmitButton(){
//how to access those text input values and add to array
}


<FlatList
data={data}
renderItem={this.renderItem}
keyExtractor={(item, index) => item}
 />

renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {

return (
    <View>
     <Item 
        floatingLabel 
        style={styles.InputBoxStyle}
        >
        <Label>First Name</Label>
        <Input 

          />
     </Item>
     <Item 
        floatingLabel 
         style={styles.InputBoxStyle}>
         <Label>Last Name</Label>
        <Input 

          />
      </Item>
<Button rounded
        onPress={this.SubmitButton}>
        <Text>Submit</Text>
     </Button>

    </View>
 );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the text of inputs in your state. Just listen for `onChangeText` event. Try to add this to your input :

```
onChangeText={val => updateState(index, val) />
```

Where `index` is your item's index from renderItem function. Later add method :

```
updateState = (index,value) => {
   const Textdata = [...this.state.Textdata]; //make a copy of array
   Textdata[index] = value;
   this.setState({ Textdata: Textdata });
}
```

Then when pressing the button you can verify this array.

As another example, when value from Picker component changes you can handle it in this way:

```
onValueChange={itemValue => this.setState({someNameForThisPicker: itemValue})}
```

Comment: Thank you this solution is working. How to handle picker(dropdown) & its selected state array.

Comment: Basically the same way - on some event (onChange, onPress, etc.) attach a function that will update your state. Don't forget to make a copy of the data, you're going to update.

Comment: I have tried onValueChange method by providing function to it change the state of the selected picker, Please Can you provide the sample example

Comment: I have tried given solution but still its not working. will you help where am I  going wrong? [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2j63s9877301m0o/FormPage.js?dl=0)

Comment: 86 line : `newArray[value] = index;` -> change that to `newArray[index] = value;` 
And :  swap arguments in `onValueChange` function -> `onValueChange(index: number, value: string)`